# Spring roo can't install mysql

Tags: spring, spring-roo

in the spring roo console I can not install mysql (mysql and slf4 are already in pom.xml for project) but spring roo console seems to have its own list and no way to install jdbc dependency. 
I am trying to run the command:

```
database reverse engineer --package ~.domain --schema testdb
```

steps done:

```
project --topLevelPackage com.testdb.spring.roo
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL --databaseName testdb
download status
download accept terms of use

#tried this from spring bug reports - didn't work
#tried this as well and didn't work -> http://lalyos.github.io/blog/2012/09/24/spring-roobot-workaround/
osgi obr url add --url http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/repository.xml
osgi obr deploy --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java

database reverse engineer --package ~.domain --schema testdb
```

here is the log from tring to run addon install id:
(trying to addon install slf4j-api etc doesn't work either)

```
roo> addon search jdbc
9 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.3 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 Y Y 5.1.18.0001 #jdbcdriver driverclass:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. This bundle
       wraps the standard Maven artifact: mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.
02 Y Y 10.8.2.2_0001 Derby Client #jdbcdriver
       driverclass:org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver. This bundle wraps the...
03 Y Y 1.2.4.0010 #jdbcdriver driverclass:net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact: jtds-1.2.4.
04 Y Y 9.1.0.901-1_0001 Postgres #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.postgresql.Driver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact:...
05 Y Y 9.1.0.901_0001 Postgres #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.postgresql.Driver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact:...
06 Y Y 1.3.170.0001 H2 #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.h2.Driver. This bundle wraps
       the standard Maven artifact: h2-1.3.170.
07 Y Y 2.1.6.0020 #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver. This
       bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact: firebird-2.1.6.
08 Y Y 10.8.2.2_0001 Derby #jdbcdriver
       driverclass:org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver. This bundle wraps...
09 Y Y 6.7.0.0010 #jdbcdriver driverclass:com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact: jtopen-6.7.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
roo> addon install id --searchResultId 01
roo> Target resource(s):
-------------------
   Spring Roo - Wrapping - mysql-connector-java (5.1.18.0001)

Required resource(s):
---------------------
   slf4j-nop (1.6.1)
   slf4j-api (1.6.1)

Deploying...
done.

roo> 
roo> database reverse engineer --package ~.domain --schema testdb
Located add-on that may offer this JDBC driver
1 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.3 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 Y Y 5.1.18.0001 #jdbcdriver driverclass:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. This...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
JDBC driver not available for 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
roo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with

osgi install --url file:\\D:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar